# ListView item record WindowsForms

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a database that consists of an array and I use a ListView to show the data that the users want to see using this code besides of other pieces of code that are less relevant:

```
lsvResultados.Items.Clear();
i = 0;
do
{
    if (value == database[i,attribute])
    {
        ListViewItem Inmueble = new ListViewItem(numdatabase[i, 5].ToString());        
        Inmueble.SubItems.Add(database[i, 0]);
        Inmueble.SubItems.Add(database[i, 1]);
        Inmueble.SubItems.Add(database[i, 2]);
        Inmueble.SubItems.Add(numdatabase[i, 0].ToString());
        Inmueble.SubItems.Add(numdatabase[i, 1] + " m²");
        Inmueble.SubItems.Add(SacarPorcentaje(numdatabase[i, 1], numdatabase[i, 2]) + " m² (" + numdatabase[i, 2] + "%)");
        Inmueble.SubItems.Add("S/. " + numdatabase[i, 3]);
        Inmueble.SubItems.Add(numdatabase[i, 4].ToString());
        Inmueble.SubItems.Add(database[i, 3]);
        Inmueble.SubItems.Add(database[i, 4]);
        lsvResultados.Items.Add(Inmueble);
    }
    i++;
} while (i < TotalInmuebles);
//yes I know I´m using do-while
```

The variable "value" is what the user wants to search and this code shows results of the search in the ListView control, so when the user selects another value the items are cleared and displays another set of items in the ListView control

My question is how can I go back to the previous results and also go to the next results, I mean how to save the last results that were in the ListView and show them when pressing a button for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store the search values you would create and maintain a

```
List<string> searchValues = new List<string>();
```

To store one set of results you would create and maintain a

```
List<ListViewItems> searchResult = new List<ListViewItems>();
```

To store more or all sets of results you would create and maintain a

```
List<List<ListViewItems>> searchResults = new List<List<ListViewItems>>();
```

You also may want to include the search values and instead of a `List<ListViewItems>` create a 
`Dictionary<string, List<ListViewItems>>`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be saving two separate list of SubItems, one for previous one for next. When the button is pressed you would clear the list view's item source and make it using the appropriate one (next/previous)

You could theoretically make a big list cache for every entry returned from the data base every single time to minimize database calls, but would consume lots of memory. So you will have to decide which one is more suitable for you